# Passing a NSManagedObject between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, nsmanagedobject

I am trying to pass a `NSManagedObject` between 2 `ViewControllers`.
For this I am using a global variable.

In the first `viewcontroller` I have, on the top (as a global variable):

```
var choosenItem : NSManagedObject? = nil
```

I build my table view and i have this:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let choosenOne = listOfLands[indexPath.row]
    let choosenItem = listOfLands[indexPath.row]


    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)

    print(choosenOne.objectID)
    print(choosenItem.objectID)

}
```

when I print the chosen objectId I got them. so I think in this `ViewController` everything is working ok.

In ViewController2 I have this:

```
   override func viewDidLoad() {

 print(thatLand?.objectID) //result is nil

}
```

Now I am not sure why I get nil in the second `ViewController`.
Is there a way to pass the `NSManagedObject` like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass that `choosenItem` by assigning it to the `thatLand` property of `ViewController2` also you need to explicitly cast the `UIViewController` to `ViewController2`.

```
let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewCotroller2 //Cast as ViewController name

//Now set thatLand property with your array's selected object before pushing it to Navigation stack
viewController.thatLand = listOfLands[indexPath.row]

self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController!, animated: true)
```

Comment: Done that. Now when I do this "viewController.thatLand = listOfLands[indexPath.row]" I get a message saying that ViewController2 has not a member "thatLand". How can I initialize "thatLand" in vc2?

Comment: @H.N. I'm talking about this `print(thatLand?.objectID)` you have mention on your question.

Comment: So do I. I did has you told. I think It«s ok. But now I get "Value of type ViewController2 as no member thatLand".

Comment: @H.N. If you doesn't have then create one  `var thatLand : NSManagedObject?`

Comment: @H.N. Welcome mate :)